# overlaying refresh icon on gif that loops just once

Tags: html, css

I'd like to find out if I could overlay a refresh icon on top right of a gif that loops only once.

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVRJN.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to elaborate more of your question, maybe show the thing that you want achieve. So anyone can see the bigger picture of your question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i've added an image.